# PHP: Get array from nested foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to get the items form an rss feed so I can display them on my blog. For some reason when I **print_r** an array outside the foreach loop it only displays one item instead of the two that are supposed to be there.

My foreach looks like this:

```
$arr_postContent = array();

foreach ($feed as $row) {

    $feedid = $row->id;
    $feedurl = $row->blogUrl;

    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );


        $postContent = array('link' => $item['link'], 'title' => $item['title']);
        $arr_postContent['site'] = $postContent;
    }

 [ STEP ONE ]
}

[ STEP TWO ]
```

Where I have put **[ STEP ONE ]** and **[ STEP TWO ]** I put the code:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr_postContent);
echo '</pre>';
```

**[ STEP ONE ]** gives me :

```
Array
(
[site] => Array
    (
        [link] => siteurl1
        [title] => site title1
    )

)
Array
(
[site] => Array
    (
        [link] => siteurl2
        [title] => site title2
    )

)
```

**[ STEP TWO ]** gives me:

```
 Array
(
[site] => Array
    (
        [link] => siteurl1
        [title] => site title1
    )

)
```

can someone tell me why It is only giving me one of the results and show me how to get both of them to output in **[ STEP TWO ]**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array key needs to be unique. because if you use the same key twice it will overwrite the previous value for that key. that's why [step two] only giving you one of the results.

Multidimensional Array would certainly be one option.

```
$arr_postContent[]['site'] = $postContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are using `item(0)`

```
/* foreach example 4: multi-dimensional arrays */
$a = array();
$a[0][0] = "a";
$a[0][1] = "b";
$a[1][0] = "y";
$a[1][1] = "z";

foreach ($a as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "$v2\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which array do I change to this?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a multi-dimensional array inside [site] array. Now it is only one dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies where: `$arr_postContent['site'] = $postContent;`

It outputs fine inside the loop because you are printing it on each time through. Once it is outside of the loop, the 'site' array key is reset to the first value that was output because the second (inner) loop stopped on the last run through. You will have to have a dynamic array key to keep all of your values the way you intend.

Without knowing your input values/format I cannot tell you if this is a definite answer. But skimming over the code, this is what I believe is happening. Hope this helps!